# How to access the localstorage value of a specific key

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have stored the local variable with key and array of values. I have used get to obtain the local stored variables. But not sure, how to get the local stored values by the specific name. 
//Example
Key
1410 
Value
{"variant":123456,"state":"passed"}
In here, I wish to get the value of the state "passed"

I have tried to get the values using the localStorage.getItem('1410');

```
 const campaignState = localStorage.getItem('1410');
 const x = campaignState;
//output - {"variant":123456,"state":"passed"}
```

Expected output - x = passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web storage stores **strings**. It looks like when storing your item, you converted it to JSON (which is a common pattern). That means that when you retrieve your item, you have to convert it *from* JSON:

```
const campaign = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("1410"));
const campaignState = campaign.state;
console.log(campaignState); // "passed"
```

If you haven't stored your item yet, `campaign` will be `null`, so you might add a guard:

```
const campaign = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("1410"));
if (campaign) {
    const campaignState = campaign.state;
    console.log(campaignState); // "passed"
} else {
    console.log("No campaign for 1410");
}
```